# Android tutorials missing from web

Tags: android

Seems like the tutorials at "developer.android.com/training/tutorials/index.html" are all missing. Hello world, note pad, views... maybe everything - I can't find any of them.

Dose anyone know what happened? 
Is this a temporary situation
Are they gone for good?

Comment: Look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

Comment: Hi Ryan: Thanks for the response, but a couple of friends of mine, and myself were working our way threw a lot of the old tutorials (Mon, Wed Fri from 9am till 11:30am) and were 2 months into the process Today everything we were working on seems to be missing (it was all there Wednesday 6/20/12 noon) and before we gave up our project, we were wondering what happened, and whether we could expect them to re-appear by Monday's session, or if we should give up the project and start fresh with a new batch of tutorials?

Comment: You're right some tutorials such as `notepad` are missing. I guess all you can do is give it some time, maybe they're working on getting it back up.

Comment: As far as I understand, Google has redesigned the whole android developers website.  They changed styles, structure, etc.  Even the API styles have changed dramatically.  It's unfortunate, but it's a fact of life.  You were relying on another company to keep some freely available information available - but unfortunately they didn't.  I'm afraid you'll have to deal with the new tutorials pointed to by @Ryan

Comment: Yeah, not a major blow, but defiantly an annoyance. If anyone hears anything official, I'd like a heads up. meanwhile, we'll prepare to start fresh with new stuff on Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android developer site changed from yesterday and they will provide all the samples to your sdk install path `<sdk>/platforms/<android-version>/samples/`. You can find samples in this path. If you are not able to find samples, download samples for your sdk through android sdk manager.